# How to solve this ODE: $y'(x) e^x = y^2(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation

$$y'(x) e^x = y^2(x) \quad (DE) $$

---

This is a Bernoulli form DE i.e $y'(x) + a(x)y(x) = b(x)y^r(x)$, where $r = 2, a(x) = 0, b(x) = \frac1e $

1. Let $u(x) = y^{1-r} = y^{-1} \iff u'(x) = -y^{-2}(x) y'(x)$
2. Then for $y \neq 0$: $(DE) = \frac{y(x)'}{y^r(x)} = e^{-x} \iff -u'(x) = -e^x (2)$

But $(2)$ is a seperate variable form ODE therefore:

$$ u(x) = e^{-x} + C \iff \frac1y = e^{-x} + C \iff $$

$$ \bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid green]{y(x) = \frac{1}{e^x + C} }$$

with $y(x) =0$, not being a solution of the DE.

---

It all seems right to me, [but wolfram has another opinion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29e%5Ex%20%3D%20y%5E2%28x%29) i.e

$$ \bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid blue]{y\left(x\right)\:=\:\frac{-e^x}{\left(Ce^x\:-\:x\:-\:1\right)}} $$

I never won an argument against Wolfie, so I am wondering what I did wrong in my solution.

Comment: The wolfram equation has an additional $x$ on the right side. You should write $y(x)^2$ when you want to input $y^2(x)$.

Comment: @Zerox aaaah, thanks!

Comment: Note that you make two algebraic mistakes in your question: $-u'(x)=e^{-x}$ and $b(x)=e^{-x}$. I followed your approach and showed how to arrive at the same answer as Wolfram Alpha. As the other answers show, you can also take different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Wolfram Alpha interprets $y^2(x)$ as $y^2\times x$. You can write $(y(x)^2)$ in Wolfram Alpha instead. The [correct input](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29e%5Ex%20%3D%20y%28x%29%5E2) in Wolfram Alpha produces:

$$y(x)=-\frac{e^x}{Ce^x-1}$$
In your solution, $b(x)=e^{-x}$. Setting $u(x) = y^{-1} \implies u'(x) = -y^{-2}(x) y'(x)$, so you should divide both sides of the original differential equation by $y^2$

$$y'(x) e^x = y^2(x)\implies \frac{y'(x)}{y^2(x)}=e^{-x}\implies -u'(x)=e^{-x}$$

Hence

$$-\frac{du(x)}{dx}=e^{-x}$$
$$-u(x)=-e^{-x}+C$$
$$-\frac{1}{y(x)}=-e^{-x}+C$$
$$y(x)=-\frac{1}{C-e^{-x}}$$

Therefore, multiplying the numerator and denominator by $e^x$ forms
$$y(x)=-\frac{e^{x}}{Ce^{x}-1}$$

Alternatively, we may write

$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{e^{-x}+C}$$

*Note: $y(x)=0$ is not a solution.*

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}e^x=y^2$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{y^2}=e^{-x}dx$$
$$\int y^{-2}dy=\int e^{-x}dx$$
$$-y^{-1}=-e^{-x}+c_1$$
$${1\over y}=e^{-x}+c_2$$

Comment: @Subhajit: When editing equations, don't put periods after $$. It will cause the periods to go on the start on the next line. I have reverted your changes back to Kim's original format.

Comment: It still have problems,at mathematical notation!see the third line please!

Comment: It has to be -2 as the power of y, but it is wrong given here, that's why I edited this one!

Comment: It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{\dot{y}}{y^2}=e^{-x}$$
as long as $y(t)\neq0$. (Notice that $y(t)\equiv0$ is a solution to your problem)

Integrating over some intervals,say $[x_0,x]$ leads to

$$
\int^x_{x_0}\frac{y'(t)}{y^2(t)}\,dt=\int^x_{x_0}e^{-t}\,dt=-e^{-t}|^x_{x_0}=e^{-x_0}-e^{-x}
$$

The integral on the left can be simplifies by change of variables $u=y$ to get

$$
-\frac{1}{y(t)}\Big|^x_{x_0}=\frac{1}{y(x_0)}-\frac{1}{y(x)}=e^{-x_0}-e^{-x}
$$

solving for $y(x)$ on gets

$$
\frac{1}{y(x)}=\frac{1}{y(x_0)}-e^{-x_0}+e^{-x}
$$
and so
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{y(x_0)^{-1}-e^{-x_0}+e^{-x}}
$$